# Constraints for views added via array

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I have an array of StackViews that is created with from a web service, using the following code

```
if !self.eventFields.isEmpty {
var i:Int = 0
for field in self.eventFields {
    if field.ControlName == "fraBackground" || field.ControlName == "picBottom" {
    } else {

        var stackedInfoView: UIStackView!

        let captionField: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.font = Style.associateMainText
            label.textColor = .darkText
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.sizeToFit()
            label.text = field.Caption
            return label
        }()

        let dataField: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.font = Style.associateSubText
            label.textColor = .darkText
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.text = "Lots of text"
            label.sizeToFit()
            return label
        }()

        stackedInfoView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [captionField, dataField])
        stackedInfoView.axis = .horizontal
        stackedInfoView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackedInfoView.alignment = .center
        stackedInfoView.spacing = 30.0
        stackedInfoView.tag = i
        stackedInfoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.viewArray.append(stackedInfoView)

        i = i + 1

    }
}
self.layoutSubViews()
}
```

When I layout subviews, I can add the views fine, however they all overlay each other because I can't work out how to add the constraints to observe the bottom anchor of the previous view. How do I achieve this? - Note, there are a certain amount of fixed views before the stack views so the following code to add the stack views and lay them out may seem unnecessarily complicated, but it's required (Unless someone can suggest a cleaner way to do it?)

```
if !self.viewArray.isEmpty {
for dynamicView in self.viewArray {
    view.addSubview(dynamicView)
    if view.tag == 0 {
        dynamicView.anchor(eventSummaryLabel.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 10, leftConstant: 20, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 20, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    } else {
        dynamicView.anchor(dynamicView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 10, leftConstant: 20, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 20, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking here. Some demo of result might be helpful...

But it seems like you are looking on how to programatically set constraints to create a list like layout. To do so for vertical (for instance) the following should do:

```
func verticallyLayoutViews(_ views: [UIView], in parent: UIView) {

    var previousView: UIView?

    views.forEach { view in
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        parent.addSubview(view)
        if let previousView = previousView {
            parent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: previousView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        }
        parent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        parent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

        previousView = view
    }

    // Set first constraint
    if let first = views.first {
       parent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: first, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        // Set last constraint
        if let last = previousView {
            parent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: last, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        }
    }


}
```